# Hive External Table is pointing to old location after altering the location to new path

Tags: hive, hive-partitions, hiveddl

Initially I create a `Hive external` table following location

> hdfs://user/temp2

and then I altered the location to following.

> hdfs://user/temp3

Now even after running `MSCK repair table` my table is pointing to **old location** (hdfs://user/temp2)

The table is dynamically partitioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is your table is partitioned and partitions have their own old locations. For **external** table the easiest way is to drop and create table + repair table, this will create partitions on top of new location subdirectories.

Steps to be done are:

```
DROP TABLE abc;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE abc ... location 'hdfs://user/temp3';

MSCK REPAIR TABLE abc;
```